# how to use IEquatable<T> with field match Proper and lower in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, bindingsource, bindinglist, iequatable

How to solve the field match between lower and proper so that the results become one row in the DataGridView and only update the number.

Is there something wrong with my code?  and please guide me.

is there anything wrong the method i use?

Thanks

below is the code I used

```
        ' Implementing IEquatable<T> interface
        Public Overloads Function Equals(ByVal other As Product) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of Product).Equals
            ' If 'other' is null, return false.
            If Object.ReferenceEquals(other, Nothing) Then
                Return False
            End If

            ' Optimization for a common success case.
            If Object.ReferenceEquals(Me, other) Then
                Return True
            End If

            ' If run-time types are not exactly the same, return false.
            If Me.GetType() IsNot other.GetType() Then
                Return False
            End If

            ' Return true if the fields match.
            Return [Date] = other.Date AndAlso Code = other.Code AndAlso Name = other.Name
        End Function
    End Class
```

[image: Screenshot_2023_09_12-2]

Comment: Your question is basically how to do a case-insensitive comparison of two strings and it seems clear that you haven't actually searched for that on the web. You need to use a search engine before posting a question here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,  please guide me

Comment: Don't know if this applies here or not but "If you implement IEquatable<T>, you should also implement IComparable<T> if instances of your type can be ordered or sorted."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing

```vb
Name = other.Name
```

compare with

```vb
String.Compare(Name, other.Name, ignoreCase:=True) = 0
```

The whole line then reads:

```vb
Return [Date] = other.Date AndAlso Code = other.Code AndAlso String.Compare(Name, other.Name, ignoreCase:=True) = 0
```

This is not the only possibility. See also: [Best practices for comparing strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings) (if the page displays with C#, you can switch to VB at the top-right of the page).

Alternatively, as @jmcilhinney pointed out, you can use

```vb
Name.Equals(other.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

where you have the choice between `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` and `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.
This returns a `Boolean`.

Comment: ,Thank you for your reply but I try with your answer `Return [Date] = other.Date AndAlso Code = other.Code AndAlso CBool(String.Compare(Name, other.Name, ignoreCase:=True))`  I tried to add button but it became several rows appeared

Comment: Oh, I missed a detail. `String.Compare` returns an Integer. So it must be `String.Compare(Name, other.Name, ignoreCase:=True) = 0`. This returns `"name 1"` and also `"Name 1"` if you search for `"name"`.

Comment: Your answer went perfectly. `Return [Date] = other.Date AndAlso Code = other.Code AndAlso CBool(String.Compare(Name, other.Name, ignoreCase:=CInt(True) = 0))`

Comment: `CBool` is not necessary, because `String.Compare(...) = 0` returns a `Boolean` already.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use `String.Equals`, which also can ignore case and already returns a `Boolean`. `String.Compare` should be used for relative ordering.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your recommendation

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes ,thanks also for the update or alternative . It's true that you said there are several options So I use `It's true that you said there are several options`